# PHP \DateInterval calculation number of months incorrect

Tags: php, datetime, dateinterval

Since the PHP timezone was changed in a project, `\DateTime::diff` does not longer calculate the number of months between two dates correctly.

Here is some example code to reproduce the problem:

```php
<pre>
<?php

$tz = new \DateTimeZone('UTC');

$start = new \DateTime('2020-04-01', $tz);
$end = new \DateTime('2020-04-30', $tz);
$end->modify('+1 days');
$diff = $end->diff($start);

print "Result with UTC TimeZone:\n";
print_r($diff);

// $diff[m] == 1   and $diff[d] == 0

//---With Different Timezone (Europe/Berlin)

$tz = new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin');

$start = new \DateTime('2020-04-01', $tz);
$end = new \DateTime('2020-04-30', $tz);
$end->modify('+1 days');
$diff = $end->diff($start);

print "\n\nResult with Europe/Berlin TimeZone:\n";
print_r($diff);

//---------> Returns: $diff[m] == 0   and $diff[d] == 30

//With Different Timezone and Time 00:00:00  (Europe/Berlin)

$tz = new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin');

$start = new \DateTime('2020-04-01 00:00:00', $tz);
$end = new \DateTime('2020-04-30 00:00:00', $tz);
$end->modify('+1 days');
$diff = $end->diff($start);

print "\n\nResult with Europe/Berlin TimeZone and 00:00 Time:\n";
print_r($diff);

//---------> Returns: $diff[m] == 0   and $diff[d] == 30

//---With Different Timezone and Time Part and Time 10:00:00  (Europe/Berlin)

$tz = new \DateTimeZone('Europe/Berlin');

$start = new \DateTime('2020-04-01 10:00:00', $tz);
$end = new \DateTime('2020-04-30 10:00:00', $tz);
$end->modify('+1 days');
$diff = $end->diff($start);

print "\n\nResult with Europe/Berlin TimeZone and 10:00 Time:\n";
print_r($diff);

//---------> Returns: $diff[m] == 1   and $diff[d] == 0
```

Any idea? Is this a bug in the PHP Date Lib?

I'm using 8.0.6.

Comment: You're probably running into DST changing during that period, and it doesn't fill up one full month due to that…

Comment: It seems you're not the only one who noticed it: https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.date-diff.php#125975

Comment: Thanks for the idea, but the DST is not in the period. A new finding, is that the problem seems to affect only months with 30 days.

Comment: Possible interpretation - There are always 30 days of difference between 1 may and 1 apr. But if you are into "April context", than 30 days is "1 month", if you are in "May context", then one month is made of 31 days, so it tells you "just" 30 days.